# Evaluate $\int \int_ S(x^4 +y^4 +z^4)dS $

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $a >0$ and let $ S=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 +y^2 +z^2=a^2\}$

Evaluate   $$\int \int_ S(x^4 +y^4 +z^4)dS   $$

**My attempt** :Let $\mathbf{F}(x,y,z) = a(x^3 ,y^3, z^3)$. . By divergence theorem, we have
\begin{align*}
\iint_{S} (x^4 + y^4 + z^4)\; dS &= \iint_{S} \mathbf{F} \cdot d\vec{S} = \iiint_{S} \text{div} \mathbf{F} dV \\
&=  \iiint_{S} 3a(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) dV  
\end{align*}

After that im not able to proceed  further

Comment: Take into account the spherical change of variables where: $x = \rho \sin{\varphi} \cos{\theta}$, $y = \rho \sin{\varphi} \sin{\theta}$, and $z = \rho \cos{\varphi}$. Allways remember the jacobian and notice $a = \rho$

Comment: As a followup,  anytime your region is a sphere/ball, you should definitely try spherical coordinates as one of your first go-tos...and the conversion is even simpler since $x^2+y^2+z^2=\rho ^2$

Comment: @PabloValentinCortesCastillo The OP is expressing the integrand $x^4+y^4+z^4$ in the form $\vec{F}\cdot \vec{n}$ where $\vec{F}=a\big<x^3,y^3,z^3\big>$ and $\vec{n}$ is the unit normal $\vec{n}=\frac{1}{a}\big<x,y,z\big>$ and then applying divergence theorem.

Comment: To the OP: The domain of your triple integral is no longer $S$ but the ball of radius $a$ centered around the origin $(0,0,0)$ which you may denote as $E$. Converting this triple integral to spherical coordinates should follow naturally.

Comment: It translates to $\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^a 3 a \rho^4 \sin\phi \ d\rho \ d\phi \ d\theta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By symmetry this is$$\begin{align}\iint_S3x^4dS&=\iint3a^4\cos^4\varphi\sin^4\theta a^2\sin\theta d\theta d\varphi\\&=3a^6\int_0^\pi\sin^5\theta d\theta\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^4\varphi d\varphi\\&=24a^6\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^5\theta d\theta\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^4\varphi d\varphi\\&=6a^6\operatorname{B}(3,\,\tfrac12)\operatorname{B}(\tfrac52,\,\tfrac12)\\&=6\pi a^6\frac{\Gamma(5/2)}{\Gamma(7/2)}\\&=\frac{12}{5}\pi a^6.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

we  will used [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Example_3:_spherical-Cartesian_transformation) for spherical cartesian transformation

using Gauss's Theorem we obtain

$$
\begin{align}
   \iiint_{S} 3a(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) dV = \int_0^{2\pi} \hspace{-5pt} \int_0^{\pi} \hspace{-5pt} \int_0^a (3ar^2) \cdot (r^2 \sin \varphi) \, \text{d} r \, \text{d} \varphi \, \text{d} \theta \\
 & = 3a \int_0^{2\pi} \hspace{-5pt} \text{d} \theta \int_0^{\pi} \hspace{-5pt} \sin \varphi \, \text{d} \varphi \int_0^a \hspace{-3pt} r^4 \, \text{d} r \\
 & = \frac{12 \pi}{5}a^6.
\end{align}
$$